# Is it possible to submit a form inside a modal panel and get the results within that same modal panel?

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have this modal panel and I want the user to be able to submit a search from within it and then get the results from that search below in the modal panel. If it is possible could someone point me in the right direction of how to do this? I have searched google but could not find anything.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Just submit by ajax and render a part while keeping the dialog open (i.e. do not explicitly close it by synchronous request or by JavaScript).

E.g.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="query" value="#{bean.query}" />
    <a4j:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.search}" execute="query" render="results" />

    <h:panelGroup id="results">
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.results}" var="result" rendered="#{not empty bean.results}">
            ...
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void search() {
    results = service.search(query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks once again BalusC for the quick response I will be trying this out now.

Comment: Does this require the newest richfaces? I am getting this error: `Attribute execute invalid for tag commandButton according to TLD`

I see that it is in 4.2 but I am on 3.3 right now thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I assumed RF 4.x, because you tagged JSF 2.0. RF 3.3 is not officially JSF 2.0 supported (it works only with some hacks). Remove the `execute` attribute and replace the `render` attribute by `reRender`.